# Reusable layout templates Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a bunch of screens that follow one of two main layouts.  I'm trying to figure out a way that I could turn them into page templates and reuse them to cut down on repeating all the boiler plate markup.  I already have reusable components for things like headers, footers, etc.  My first attempt was to create layout component building blocks that use ng-content to insert the content that is different for each page.  I wanted to have something like this:

```
<layout>
    <layout-header>
       <header title="..."></header>
    </layout-header>
    <layout-content>
       <layout-left>
           <div> -- LEFT CONTENT GOES HERE -- </div>
       </layout-left>
       <layout-right>
           <div> -- RIGHT CONTENT GOES HERE -- </div>
       </layout-right>
    </layout-content>
    <layout-footer>
       <footer></footer>
    </layout-footer>
</layout>
```

The idea is that each component (layout, layout-header, etc) would produce the n lines of layout markup that I had been copying into each page.  I am using bootstrap to do the actual layout within each component's template.  The template for the main layout component looks something like this:

```
<div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <ng-content select="layout-header"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="layout-content"></ng-content>
    <ng-content select="layout-footer"></ng-content>
</div>
```

This looked like it would work but the main problem is that the host tags, layout-right for example, stay in the resulting markup and interfere with the actual layout.  I could do something like this (but I don't want to):

```
<layout class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <layout-header class="...">
       <header title="..."></header>
    </layout-header>
    <layout-content class="...">
       <layout-left class="...">
           <div> -- LEFT CONTENT GOES HERE -- </div>
       </layout-left>
       <layout-right class="...">
           <div> -- RIGHT CONTENT GOES HERE -- </div>
       </layout-right>
    </layout-content>
    <layout-footer class="...">
       <footer></footer>
    </layout-footer>
</layout>
```

Having to repeat the classes in every page kind of defeats the purpose.

Anyhow, wondering if there is an Angular way of building reusable layouts like this?  Or is there something I'm just missing?